# Is there a Java code coverage tool that records the number of times lines and methods are called?

Tags: java, code-coverage

Hopefully the title describes what I'm after.  The closest I've found is [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) which looks like it will record the number of times a given line of code is called, but I haven't found anything at all to count how often a method is called.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins available if you are using an IDE like eclipse
Check this out :-
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Eclipse [Test & Performance Tools Platform Project](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) with good results - it will not only tell you the number of times a method is called but also measure how long every method took to execute so that you can used if for performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

What about [EclEmma's Method Coverage Indicator](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/coverageproperties.html)

Answer (score 1):

[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) (included with Sun/Oracle JDK) can do that for you.

From CPU Profiling section of the [Profiling Applications document](http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html):

> This profile command returns detailed data on method-level CPU performance (execution time), showing the total execution time and number of invocations for each method.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is running persistently, you could always just implement a static variable and count it yourself.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good idea, as this method would use memory in the running program.

Answer (score 0):

Our [Java (Counting) Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/JavaProfiler.html) comes pretty close to exactly what OP wants.

It counts entries into every basic block in the Java code; this includes method entry points and any subsidiary blocks to control statements (if, while, try, ...).  This achieves the same effective result as count executions of individual "lines" (not sure what that means exactly in a Java program but we'll let that go) with considerably lower overhead.

The count data can be treated like coverage data; nonzero means "covered".